# Weak topology and separation

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ have the weak topology induced from the collection of functions $f_\alpha\colon X\to X_\alpha$, for $\alpha\in A$. I am trying to show that $x,y\in X$ s.t. $x \neq y$, $\exists\alpha\in A: f_{\alpha}(x)\neq f_{\alpha}(y)$ does not imply whenever $B$ is closed in $X$ and $x\notin B$, then for $\alpha\in A$, $f_{\alpha}(x)\notin \overline{f_\alpha[B]}$.

I consider first the subspace topology via the inclusion map, however, it satisfies both properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $X=\prod_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$, and let $f_\alpha:X\to X_\alpha$ be the projection map. You can even take $A=\{0,1\}$ and $X_0=X_1=\Bbb R$.

Comment: So, just to make sure I am interpreting the *premise* correctly, $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ with the product topology (box topology since it's a finite product?).

Comment: @D.Math: Yes, exactly.

Comment: I *think* I may have found a point and set that works. Let $B:=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $x:=(0,2)$. Then, clearly $x\not\in B$ but $\pi_0(x)= 0\in[0,1] = \overline{\pi_0(B)}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Just now realizing that doesn't work, since $\pi_1(x)\not\in\overline{\pi_1[B]}$...

Comment: @D.Math: Take $B$ to be the graph of $y=x$.

Comment: Let $B:=\{(y,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Let $x:=(0,1)$. Then, clearly $x\not\in B$ but $\pi_0(x) = 0\in\mathbb{R} = \overline{\pi_0[B]}$ and $\pi_1(x) = 1\in\mathbb{R} = \overline{\pi_1[B]}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @D.Math: It is. And since $\pi_0[B]=\pi_1[B]=\Bbb R$, it’s impossible to separate $B$ from  **any** point.

Comment: I see. Thank you *very* much, Brian!

Comment: @D.Math: You’re very welcome.